# Using BindingSource is very slow to load data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bindingsource

i 'm loading 100000 records with Entity Framework and MS Sql Server 2008 in my project

this records are loaded in 3 seconds
when i using code like below

```
class BLChequePay
{
    ....

    public List<ChequePay> GetAll()
    {
        var Context = new AccountingEntities();
        var Che = Context.ChequePays;
        return Che.ToList();
    }
}

private void ChequePayForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  radGridView1.DataSource = ChequePays.GetAll();
}
```

but when i using BindingSource they are loaded in 50 seconds .
i use BindingSource control for connecting other controls such as textbox, datetimepicker, spinbutton and other

```
private void ChequePayForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  chequePayBindingSource.DataSource = ChequPays.GetAll();
}
```

how to reduce loading time ?

Comment: It might do good to isolate the problem even more.

Comment: "i 'm loading 100000 records" - that might be your problem. Do you really expect users to read 100,000 items? Perhaps paging might be more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly change the `List<ChequePay>` into `IEnumerable<ChequePay>` - and remove the ToList() as ToList usually causes all items to be realised (i.e. fetched).

Answer (score 1):

[richard-harrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19624/richard-harrison) i have had this problem and i could not solve it i think main problem is BindingSource because 100000 or more are loaded in 3 or 4 second but when i used BindingSource the records are loaded in 1 minute